# python libclang: How to distinguish const vs constexpr types?

Tags: python, c++, constexpr, libclang

How can we determine if the type of a variable declaration is a constexpr in libclang?
(In case it matters, I am using the python bindings)

---

Here is an example to play with.
I have not been able to figure out how to distinguish a 'const' vs 'constexpr' declaration.

file: a.cpp

```cpp
constexpr int a = 1;
const int b = 1;
```

file: test.py

```py
import clang.cindex

def treePrint(cursor,pad=""):
    print("{}{} : {}".format(pad,cursor.kind,cursor))
    for child in cursor.get_children():
        treePrint(child,pad+"  ")

clang.cindex.Config.set_library_path("/usr/lib/llvm-6.0//lib/")
index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
translation_unit = index.parse("a.cpp", args=["-std=c++17"])

c = translation_unit.cursor
print('-- tree', '-'*60)
treePrint(c)
print('-'*70)

CursorKind = clang.cindex.CursorKind
varDecls = [x for x in c.get_children() if x.kind == CursorKind.VAR_DECL]

for vDecl in varDecls:
    print("{} : {}".format(vDecl.spelling, vDecl.type.spelling))
```

run: `python3 test.py`
console output:

```
-- tree ------------------------------------------------------------
CursorKind.TRANSLATION_UNIT : <clang.cindex.Cursor object at 0x7fc60e776ae8>
  CursorKind.VAR_DECL : <clang.cindex.Cursor object at 0x7fc60e776c80>
    CursorKind.INTEGER_LITERAL : <clang.cindex.Cursor object at 0x7fc60e776d90>
  CursorKind.VAR_DECL : <clang.cindex.Cursor object at 0x7fc60e776d08>
    CursorKind.INTEGER_LITERAL : <clang.cindex.Cursor object at 0x7fc60e776b70>
----------------------------------------------------------------------
a : const int
b : const int
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no supported way to check for constexpr in libclang.  I resorted to checking if any of the tokens in the declaration is "consexpr", which doesn't catch typedefs, preprocessor uses, etc. which could cause it to still be a constexpr. This article discusses similar hacks https://foonathan.net/2017/04/cppast/ and I agree with the frustration the author expresses.